# Adjust a table in HTML

Tags: excel, vba

to be honest, I have no knowledge of VBA programming, however, based on the questions & answers on this platform I put together a code that actually works OK (copies a table, creates and e-mail and pastes the table into e-mail)

I would need a help with minor adjustments to achieve the following results:

1. column A should contain Pasted Values of column K (my VBA code does not recongnise e-mail address when
   theres is VLOOKUP formula behind)
2. hiding columns A and K when pasting into e-mail
3. optimise column width when pasting into e-mail
4. put "sent" into column L once the e-mail has been sent to the recipient

[image]

Here's the CODE:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test1()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim cell2 As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim WS As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hlavnat")
    
    On Error GoTo cleanup
    For Each cell In WS.Columns("A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" Then

                If dict.exists(cell.Value) = False Then

                dict.Add cell.Value, ""
                Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
                Set rng = WS.UsedRange.Rows(1)

                    For Each cell2 In WS.UsedRange.Columns(1).Cells
                    If cell2.Value = cell.Value Then
                        Set rng = Application.Union(rng, WS.UsedRange.Rows(cell2.Row))
                    End If
                Next cell2
                
           
                
                On Error Resume Next
                With OutMail
                    .To = cell.Value
                    .Subject = "Navolané kontakty"
                    .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
                    .Display
                End With

                On Error GoTo 0
                Set OutMail = Nothing
            End If
        End If
    Next cell

cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook
    
 
    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

   
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With


    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    Kill TempFile
    
    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: I see that you omit Option Explicit. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: Option Explicit is an excellent first troubleshooting tool. Edit your post to reflect that you included it. Did any errors pop up when you did compile?

Comment: I added Option Explicit, it runs OK as I said - no errors. Now I would kindly need someone to help me to incorporate commands that would achieve the actions oultlined in my question. Many thanks

Comment: This is not a free programming service where you state what you want and the software for the requested solution is delivered. You need to show us what is not working (errors?), what you have tried, in fact you need to follow these guidelines:https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Look, I spent 3 days creating the code and I am in the situation when I need to add 3 lines to complete the task. Hope someone can help me.